# Functions for taking in binary string input then converting to decimal PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am trying to write a simple program that takes in input, turns it into a binary string and then using another function, takes the input and converts it to decimal. I also need it to work for non-integer numbers. This is what I have so far, any help I can get would be great!

```
def taking_info():
    x = (int(input("Enter in a string of binary digits")))
    return bin(x)

def conversion(x):
    print (int(x, 2))

taking_info()
conversion(taking_info)
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-integer numbers?

Comment: I assume he wants something like "4.75" to translate into "100.11" and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe the OP means in alternate bases? As in hex, oct, etc.? That would just mean passing `0` as the second argument to the `int` constructor so it will deduce the base, e.g. `x = int(input("Enter in a string of binary digits"), 0)`? Or if the goal is to read a sequence of `0`s and `1`s without a `0b` prefix, you'd pass `2` instead of `0` as the second argument.

Comment: Well, the issue is the code isn't working, i tried what you suggested and i keep getting an error message that int() can't convert non-string with explicit base. and Yes, I want it to work for numbers with decimals as well, thanks!

Comment: @Meenajoumaa it didnt work because you probably entered `int(11,2)` instead of `int('11',2)`. Use the above suggestion exactly as it is and it will work. Also converting decimals like `3.75` to binary wont be easy; there are limitations in expressing floating-point decimal numbers in binary exactly. You will have to decide how much precision you want.